# Partitioning /home for desktop workstation (HDD+SSD)

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, home-directory, user-management

I just switched my wife's home computer to Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10, and she's liking the transition so far. It's an Ubuntu-only machine (no dual boot, only one OS distro, may need to set up a VM for certain Windows-specific applications).

One last thing to figure out and set up is how to handle the two drives (480GBb SSD, 1TB HDD). Tried installing with LVM enabled, but ran into the `lvmetad` issue and had to go with standard `ext4` partitions (i.e., just `/efi` and `/` on the SSD, single unmounted `ext4` partition on the HDD that has the archive of her user data). She has almost 500gb of archaeological research data (many confidential/proprietary photos, .pdf's, and other data files) that would obviously overwhelm the SSD.

I'm trying to figure out how to set up so that `/home` stays on the ssd (for speed, etc), with the bulk of the archival on the HDD. I'm not sure I want to just mount the HDD (e.g., as `/archive`) with links to `/home`, though, since I want whatever is pushed off to the HDD to also be exclusively part of her user space (i.e., not just generic storage accessible/visible to any other user account). Ideally, what I want is to create a subspace of `~/home` on the HDD and have it usable and understandable to someone that has no interest in filesystem management and needs it to "just work" so that she can get to her data.

So far, all the two+ drive solutions I've seen just mount the HDD as bulk storage symlinked under `/home`, sets up `/home` as an LVM pseudo-RAID across the two (opinions vary whether that is a good idea, and `lvmetad` prevents it for now anyway), or sets up an *actual* RAID (which I don't want to get into).

Unfortunately, all of this a hair beyond my understanding of Linux filesytems and it is **very** possible that I'm just not understanding this all correctly.

Desired setup:

- Allow setup of multi-user system, with `\home` on the SSD and individual user access to large-file storage on the HDD
- user files and directories on HDD accessible only to that user, and linked under the user's `/home`
- `/home/[user]/[extra storage]` on the SSD linked to `[hdd mount point]/[user]` visible/accessible only to [user] as `~/[extra storage]`
- quotas not necessary but possible storage for space on the HDD

Basically, separate and secure individual user shares on the bulk storage device -- extending the user's home directory -- without pushing all of `/home` to that second device.

Is there a way to set up what I'm describing, or can someone please point out where my thinking about the user filesystem structure is off-base?

Comment: Is this then a multiple user system? I am not familiar with that as my wife & I just share one /home. If so then you need to get into separate ownership & permission settings and oir groups. Standard linking: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Some info on groups: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138476

Comment: @oldfred I'm approaching it as a multi-user setup just in case, and to incorporate user account security since much of it is confidential data.

Comment: @PerlDuck that might work, but does that fix the whole drive to just her account or can it be a share on the physical drive for multi-user setup?

Comment: @PerlDuck would or could that make each user's sub-directories and access separate within the shared drive? Maybe that's a better way to describe what I'm aiming at... individual user shares within a bulk storage mount point? If so, could you post an answer on how to go about setting that up? This is new territory for me... never had to deal with multiple physical drives before.

Comment: @PerlDuck if user `alice` would effectively see `/archive/alice == /home/alice/archive` as `~/archive`, then yes that looks like what I'm aiming at. I'll read up on the link you provided, but an overview answer would be very appreciated.

Comment: @user68186 I've edited the question... does that match what is preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps describe how to mount the partition on your HDD 
below `/mnt/archive` and then add [*bind mounts*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) to the home directories
of two users, *alice* and *bob*. The home directories themselves are
still on another partition.

All commands must be issued as user `root`.

1. Determine UUID of `archive` partition:

   ```
   lsblk -fs
   NAME      FSTYPE      LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
   sda5      ext4        slash       467ddc36-vvvv-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz /
   └─sda                                                                  
   sda6      ext4        home        a87c2c2d-vvvv-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz /home
   └─sda                                                                  
   sdb8      ext4        archive     291bd44c-vvvv-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz 
   └─sdb                                                                  
   ...
   ```

   In my case, I have `/` and `/home` on `sda` and an unmounted
   partition labelled `archive` on `sdb8`. For the purpose of this post
   we assume `sda` is an SSD and `sdb` is an HDD.
2. Mount the archive partition into an empty directory, say `/mnt/archive`:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/archive
   mount UUID=291bd44c-vvvv-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz /mnt/archive
   chown root:root /mnt/archive
   chmod 750 /mnt/archive
   ```
3. Create user specific folders below `/mnt/archive` (i.e. on the HDD) 
   for users *alice* and *bob* and adjust the permissions so that only
   they can access these directories. Note that the directories are now
   on the partition `archive` on the HDD:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/archive/alice
   chown alice:alice /mnt/archive/alice
   chmod 750 /mnt/archive/alice

   mkdir /mnt/archive/bob
   chown bob:bob /mnt/archive/bob
   chmod 750 /mnt/archive/bob
   ```
4. Create `archive` folders in their home directories. Don't worry
   because the directories are owned by `root`. This does not hurt
   because *alice* isnt't supposed to put anything in that *directory*.
   The directory `/home/alice/archive` only serves as a location where
   to bind-mount the actual `/mnt/archive/alice` to and when it is mounted,
   the permissions and ownership of `/mnt/archive/alice` apply.

   ```
   mkdir /home/alice/archive
   mkdir /home/bob/archive
   ```
5. [*bind mount*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) `/mnt/archive/alice` to `/home/alice/archive`:

   ```
   mount -o bind /mnt/archive/alice /home/alice/archive
   mount -o bind /mnt/archive/bob /home/bob/archive
   ```
6. When satified, add the following lines to `/etc/fstab` to mount the
   partition automatically upon boot:

   ```
   # The /archive partition
   UUID=291bd44c-vvvv-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz /mnt/archive  ext4 defaults  0  2

   # bind mounts for alice and bob:
   /mnt/archive/alice /home/alice/archive  none  bind  0  0
   /mnt/archive/bob   /home/bob/archive    none  bind  0  0
   ```

**Before the *bind mount*** is done, *alice* will just see a directory owned by
*root* in her home directory. The directory is empty and she cannot (and 
should not) put files in there:

```
alice@ubuntu:~$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Jan 25 12:51 archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 alice alice 8980 Jan 25 12:43 examples.desktop
```

**After the *bind mount*** is done (`mount -o bind /mnt/archive/alice /home/alice/archive`), 
*alice* will see the directory `/mnt/archive/alice` in her home directory instead, including
the permissions of `/mnt/archive/alice`:

```
alice@ubuntu:~$ ll
total 16
drwxr-x--- 2 alice alice 4096 Jan 25 13:06 archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 alice alice 8980 Jan 25 12:43 examples.desktop
```

She can do whatever she likes in and with that `archive` directory and everything
will happen on the partition on the HDD.

---

To undo the above steps, use the following commands:

```
# undo bind-mounts:
umount /home/alice/archive
umount /home/bob/archive

# unmount actual partition:
umount /mnt/archive
```

Comment: +1 for a general solution for multiple users. For a new user it may be useful to add `sudo` to those commands that need root privileges.